# How do I duplicate pages within PDF files automatically?

Tags: pdf, duplicate, pdftk

I have a lot of PDF files with 1 to 4 pages each. I need a solution which automatically generates a new file for each of these files. The new files should contain the content of the original files twice (i.e. pages 1 through to the end, followed by the same pages in the same order again).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please clarify, we cannot read your mind. What bill? You want to generate a new pdf file that contains every page of the original twice? In what order? Do you want page 1a followed by page 1b or do you want all 4 pages first and then all four pages again? What Operating system are you using? What tool do you use to create the pdfs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solution for Windows using [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) (which you seem to be using as per your tags):

This will result in a PDF with pages 1-end followed by 1-end again:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-end 1-end output out.pdf
```

If you want each page to be duplicated together (as in 1,1,2,2,...), use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
set pages=
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('pdftk in.pdf dump_data ^| find /i "NumberOfPages"') do for /l %%b in (1,1,%%a) do set pages=!pages! %%b %%b
pdftk in.pdf cat!pages! output out.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot: "pdftk in.pdf cat 1-end 1-end output out.pdf" exactly does what I need. The only thing missing is a loop that takes all pdf files from a directory and creates all the new files.Thanx a lot for helping me again. I'll be grateful and invite my wife for a dinner with the time saved ;-)))

Comment: @Marc: The loop is easily achieved. Just go to the directory with the PDFs and at the command prompt type `for %a in (*.pdf) do @pdftk "%~a" cat 1-end 1-end output "%~na (Duplicated)%~xa"`. For each **in.pdf** (name can be anything), this will result in a corresponding **in (Duplicated).pdf**. Enjoy your dinner and don't forget to accept the answer (click the green check mark to the left) if it helped you!

Comment: infinete thanks to you - you have saved my life! I am very very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I might give you a better solution if you answer the questions in my comment but for the sake of your wife, here are couple of suggestions.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a cross-platform command line tool for image manipulation. Once you install it, you should be able to use its `convert` tool to do what you want. The details depend on your operating system. I am assuming you want two copies of the entire file, not each page doubled.

1. Linux/OSX/Unix etc

   ```
   for n in *pdf; do convert -density 150 "$n" "$n" "$n"; done
   ```

   **This will overwrite the existing files**, you may want to backup first.
2. Windows. This may well be slightly wrong, I don't use Windows so I cannot test it but the general idea should be something like this

   ```
   for %f in (*.pdf) do (convert.exe %f %f %f)
   ```

Comment: Your `for` loop is missing the `done` and `$n` should probably be quoted. Maybe I'm missing how `convert` works, but what does `convert` do when you pass three times the same file? I can't test it right now.

Comment: Thanks @slhck, you're right on both counts as usual. The general convert format is `convert infile1 infile2 ... infileN outfile`. So, if you pass it the same file three times it will take it twice as input and then write to the same file as output. That one I _did_ test :).

Comment: Oh, cool, then I learned something as well :)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Thanks a lot. The comment above: I gave that one the first try and it worked perfectly, only the right loop I am still seraching for.... could you help me again? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Marc sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Which comment? Which loop?  The windows or the bash one?

Answer (score 2):

If you want each page to be duplicated together (as in 1,1,2,2,...) on Linux, this script will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUTFILE=$*
PAGENUM=`pdftk ${INPUTFILE} dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d : -f 2  | cut -d " " -f 2`
PAGES=`seq 1 ${PAGENUM}`
DUPAGES=`for i in ${PAGES} ; do echo $i $i | tr "\n" " " ; done`
OUTPUT=`basename ${INPUTFILE} .pdf`.dup.pdf
pdftk ${INPUTFILE} cat ${DUPAGES} output ${OUTPUT}
```

Answer (score 1):

For duplicating pages in a 4 page pdf (1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4) in Linux with pdftk already installed this entry worked for me in a C shell script:

```
pdftk output.pdf cat 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 output out.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate a pdf multiple times into a new pdf, I prefer [`pdfjam`](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam). In Windows this might be hard to come by, but in Linux (or via [`wsl`](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam) in Windows) the `texlive-extra-utils` package should be easy to install.

I use it like this:

```
pdfjam input.pdf 1,1 --a4paper --scale 0.97 --pdftitle Title... --outfile output.pdf
```

The advantage of `pdfjam` over `pdftk`: the resulting pdf is much smaller. A duplicated result without duplicating the actual data!

Answer (score 0):

If you have pdftk not installed, but poppler-utils, then use this command:

```
for f in *
do
    pdfjoin $f $f
done
```

This is especially relevant on Fedora 21, where pdftk is not available in the repository any more.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `pdfunite`. This can probably be further simplified with more scripting knowledge.

Be aware that the **last argument is the resulting file**. If you forget that then this file will be overwritten.

```
pdfunite 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf 4.pdf result.pdf
pdfunite result.pdf result.pdf result.pdf 3-times-result.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

For duplicating all pages (1,1,2,2,...) of a pdf file (named `in.pdf`), you can shuffle it with itself (using pdftk):

```
pdftk A=in.pdf B=in.pdf shuffle A B output out.pdf
```